# Turning an integer into an array of rows with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Ruby 2.6
```

I have an variable (integer):

```
 num_rows = 7
```

I would like to turn it into an array of row numbers. I did:

```
rows_arr = []
num_rows = 5
i = 0
while i < num_rows
  rows_arr << "Row: #{i+1}"
  i += 1
end
```

which gives me:

```
=> ["Row: 1", "Row: 2", "Row: 3", "Row: 4", "Row: 5"]
```

Is there a cleaner, or more elegant, way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
num_rows=5
(1..num_rows).map { |n| "Row: #{n}" }
=> ["Row: 1", "Row: 2", "Row: 3", "Row: 4", "Row: 5"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nbr_rows = 5

["Row: "].product((1..nbr_rows).to_a).map(&:join)
  #["Row: 1", "Row: 2", "Row: 3", "Row: 4", "Row: 5"]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = (1..nbr_rows).to_a
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
b = ["Row: "].product(a)
  #=> [["Row: ", 1], ["Row: ", 2], ["Row: ", 3], ["Row: ", 4], ["Row: ", 5]] 
b.map(&:join)
  #=> ["Row: 1", "Row: 2", "Row: 3", "Row: 4", "Row: 5"]
```

See [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-product) and [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-join). Note that `join` converts the elements of `a` (integers) to strings.

This is just a different way to do it, using the oft-overlooked method `Array#product`. In practice I prefer @Constantin's solution, as I think it reads better.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I was not aware of the #Array#product method

Answer (score 1):

```
   rows_arr = num_rows.times.map { |i| "Row: #{i + 1}" }
```